# .pas file not found but the .dcu is there, is that not enough?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

In Delphi 7 I have in the 'Tools/Environment options/Library' under my 'Libray path' the following directory :

```
C:\ggProgramFiles\QR-synopse-pdf-files
```

In there I have some Pas files and their Dcu files.
One of the files here is QRPDFSynFilt.pas and QRPDFSynFilt.dcu

Now my problem is that since the pas files are available there I always step into them while debugging and I find that annoying.
So I made a new directory :

```
C:\ggProgramFiles\QR-synopse-pdf-files\dcu
```

and copied only the dcu files there.
Then I altered the path in 'Tools/Environment options/Library' to point to this new directory.
But now Delphi 7 tells me he cant find

```
C:\ggProgramFiles\QR-synopse-pdf-files\dcu\QRPDFSynFilt.pas
```

and that is correct only the dcu is there.
But I always believed that when Delphi finds the DCU file that would be enough, the PAS file would not be needed if the DCU is found.

So my question is does Delphi needs the PAS file to compile or is the DCU enough and if the latter is true what could cause Delphi to give me this error ?

**EDIT on Deltics answer**

I could use the compiler directive {$debuginfo OFF} but since these units are 3th party I did not wanted to edit them.
If nothing else works I will still do that.

**EDIT on Davids comment :**
the compiler error is

```
[Fatal Error] File not found 'C:\ggProgramFiles\QR-synopse-pdf-files\dcu\QRPDFSynFilt.pas'
```

Comment: Just compile the files to dcus with debug disabled in your computer options. And then provide dcus rather than pas files. If that's what you want. I would not do this but it's your choice.

Comment: I can't see any description of the error. You just need to remove the pas files from sight.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I updated the question with the exact error I get from delphi when I stop the compiler from seeing the pas files

Comment: I guess it can't see the dcus then

Comment: But they are there I checked and doublechecked

Comment: But the compiler can't see them. Look at how the compiler finds the RTL dcus

Comment: How do I do that ?

Comment: Honesty I have never worked out those details because I always i clue source files and list them all in my project file. But I think that the project search path can meet your needs no?

Comment: The project search path is empty and this folder only appears in the library path of the environment options. I also never looked in those details since I never had this problem. I have 3th party components that are setup this way so delphi cant see their pas files either and it works well (eg devexpress). So in my believe this should work and thats why I asked here

Comment: For now I will use Deltics answer. My project compiles and there is no urgent problem but I am still very curious to what causes this

Comment: Don't give up. Take some time. Experiment. Understand the behaviour.

Comment: I am not giving up but I have a deadline so I wil look into this again tomorrow

Comment: You've accepted an answer now so I guess it's over

Comment: The answer did help me in getting rid of the annoying 'step in' when debugging but I will keep looking for this. I dont like it when I dont understand something it keeps haunting me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,if you have the `dcu` then this should be enough.  Something else is wrong in your setup.  However, instead of trying to fix that and introducing and trying to deal with complexity into your build environment I would instead "*fix the first problem*".

Instead of trying to fool the compiler, just add a `{$debuginfo OFF}` to the top of any `pas` files you never want to debug:

```
{$debuginfo OFF}
```

Then regardless of compiler settings in the project, these units will never be compiled with debug info and the debugger won't step into them.  To re-enable debugging you can simply add a `.` to the directive after the `{` to turn it into a comment:

```
{.$debuginfo OFF}    // This is now just a comment, not an active directive
```

Syntax highlighting will make the difference clear (assuming you have comments and directives configured with different colors etc, which imho is a good idea anyway).

It might make sense to put this directive inside a conditional compilation directive which so that you can enable or disable debugging of these specific but related units with a project conditional:

```
{$ifdef debugQRPDF}
  {$debuginfo ON}
{$else}
  {$debuginfo OFF}
{$endif}
```

Any units with this at the top will have debug enabled or disabled not by the project compiler setting but by the project conditionals.  You then don't have to worry about trying to "hide" pas files from the compiler just to avoid debugging them.

Don't forget that when changing project settings, such as conditional directives, a FULL rebuild is required for those changes to be properly reflected in the build.

Comment: I agree something else must be wrong. I knew about the compiler directive but because they are 3th party I did not want to edit the pas files but maybe it is my only choice. I will update my question with this info

Comment: You don't need to change the Pascal files you just need to compile with no debug

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - but then the OP cannot debug **anything**, including the code they *do* wish to debug.  The only way to turn off debugging in specific files (independent of project settings which apply to everything) is to introduce directives in those specific files (or in a common `inc`lude file, if there is one that is common to only those files you wish to not debug)

Comment: Not so. Just compile those dcus without debug. Compile the ones that you want to be able to debug with debug enabled. And then do exactly what was asked in the question, and provide dcus rather than pas files.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - if they are used in the project, and recompiled in a build (and since the OP's question is quite clear that the build is looking for the **pas** files then clearly they **are** in the build), then you cannot compile "just those units" *without* debug if you are compiling the project *with* debug.  Not without a directive specifically in those files.  Unless you know better and for some reason are simply choosing not to actually explain how to achieve it ?

Comment: DCUs might be of different compiler version or settings, we do not know where they came from. Also sometimes people modify and recompile parts of RTL placing RT:'s pas-files them in the project folder.

Comment: If asker makes dcus available but not pas files then it will work exactly as I describe. So asker needs to stop the compiler seeing the pas files.

Comment: @arioch The choice depends on needs. I typically build with DCUs but not pas files for RTL and VCL. That's pretty common no?

Comment: I meant a possible situation when mORMot sources were compiled against the vanilla RTL and DCUs are being tried to compile against modified RTL. In that case it would make little difference if modified RTL was in PAS or in DCU, it is only needed the, to be different from what expected by mORMot DCUs

Comment: @DavidHeffernan That was my intention, stop the compiler from seeing the pas files. But then the compiler error appears as you can see in my question.

Comment: @Deltics I do it all the time, i have a lot of dcu without pas in the library path. We have a lot of library units without debug information. This is not a problem. There are  only problems if  compiled dcu doesn't match to another dcu or pas. David Heffernan is right

Comment: @Fritzw The DCU are build everytime i do a build of the project. So they should match all other dcu or pas files ? Or am I wrong in this ?

Answer (score 5):

You probably have the file in the project list. This effectively tells the compiler you want to compile it. You will need to remove it from your project, but leave the references in the uses clause of each unit that references it.

Comment: Im sure I checked this but its a good idea to check it again. I will do so when I am back at my office

Answer (score 2):

If it is a third party Component Library and the vendor has supplied the source you can open the Design time package and recompile it with the Debug Info turned off. This will create new dcus which the debugger will not try to debug into the associated .pas file.
You will find this setting under the Project Options. Go to Delphi Compiler -> Compiling -> Debugging -> Debug Information. Change the setting to OFF.

Comment: yes I know that but it still does not explains why i cannot compile when I hide the pas files and only let it see the dcu files

Comment: Just putting the dcu files in another directory is not enough. The must be re-compiled with debug info off first.
If the pas files the dcu was compiled from references another.pas file which don't have dcus for in the directory then you need to have .pas files available at compile time.

Comment: @GuidoG, yes that could explain, because if you don't use the .dcu's related to your Delphi version, it is as if they were not existing.
-> I reported this very misleading compiler error here -> https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-26359